# Не получается отправить данные из формы django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь отправить данные через форму Django, но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, хотя запрос на сервере проходит.

Сама форма:

```
<form class="form_contact" action="" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" id="your_name">
     <input type="email" id="your_email">
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" >
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.date }}
     <input id="datepicker" type="date">
     <script>
         $(function () {
             $("#id_date").datepicker({
                   format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
             });
         });
     </script>
     <input type="text" id="party_number" >
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book now!" id="button" />
</form>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = Form()
    else:
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['your_email']
            party = form.cleaned_data['party_number']
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            try: 
                send_mail(name, email, party, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['daribian@list.ru'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, 'constant/home.html')

def successView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success!')
```

Forms.py

```
class Form(forms.Form):
your_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'my_name_class'}),max_length=100, required=True)
your_email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'my_name_class'}),max_length=100, required=True)
party_number = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'my_email_class'}), required=True)
date = forms.DateTimeField(
    input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], 
)
```

Может ли кто-нибудь указать на ошибку?

Comment: А что именно должно происходить? Если вы имеете ввиду то, что после нажатия на "Book now!" вы остаетесь на странице формы - просто изменить action

Comment: Мой вопрос заключался несколько в другом. При нажатии на кнопку отправки формы, данные из форм должны отправляться письмом на мою электронную почту. Но этого не происходит и пытаясь выяснить эту проблему я немного запутался. Сейчас я не понимаю почему при нажатии на кнопку считывается отправка метода POST, но данные не отправляются...

Comment: Сейчас, временно, у меня индикатором правильной работы алгоритма является перенаправление на страницу с надписью "Success!". После нажатия на кнопку страница обновляется и больше ничего не происходит.